# How can I fix this batch file so that it does not error out on the IF statement?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I am pulling my hair out getting an error on this IF statement

```
IF %resultis%=="true" (
```

The batch file hits the pause right before it but right after that gets some error that goes by to fast for me to see what it is.

Here is the full script:

```
@Echo off
Echo "Adding Chrysaliser user to Users group and removing from Administrators"
REM net localgroup Users Chrysaliser /add
REM net localgroup Administrators Chrysaliser /delete

REM SET /P password= Enter ladmin user password: 
REM net user ladmin %password% /ADD
REM net localgroup Administrators ladmin /add

SET /P alaptop= Is this a laptop? (Y/N): 
echo %alaptop%
IF %alaptop%=="Y" (SET resultis="true")
IF %alaptop%=="y" (SET resultis="true")
pause
IF %resultis%=="true" (
    pause   
    SET /P password= Enter Lockedout user password: 
    pause
    net user Lockedout %password% /ADD
    net localgroup Users Lockedout /add
    net localgroup Administrators Chrysaliser /delete

)
Echo Getting install files
mkdir %SYSTEMDRIVE%\files
SET /P username= Enter your domain admin username: 
SET/P password= Enter your domain admin password:
net use \\server /user:%username% $password%
pause
```

Comment: to troubleshoot, don't run your script with a double click. Open a `cmd` window and run it manually from there. So the window keeps open and enables you to read any error messages.

Comment: and [look here](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) to improve your code a bit (see the `/i`switch). Although you should prefer the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command, as it does it's own error handling.

Comment: Thanks Stephan should have know that.

The error is "( was unexpected at this time."

It is an IF statement so not sure why it would not be expected.

Comment: run your code with `echo on` - the error should be quite obvious.

Comment: Still not seeing any issue

Comment: Found it.  The %resultis% variable was empty for some reason.  I had to remove the "" around Y and y for some reason.

Comment: You should better enclose `%resultis%` in quotes also rather than removing them...

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The %resultis% variable was empty for some reason. I had to remove the "" around Y and y for some reason.

Comment: By saying "for some reason" you seem to imply that you weren't expecting that behaviour. The way the command processor works is that the IF command (and in fact all commands) is ignorant of variables. The variables are simply expanded into their respective values and the values are substituted into the command line, which is then parsed. So it's `if "y"=="Y"` therefore you need `if "%alaptop%"=="Y"`. You can't just put `if %alaptop%=="Y"` because that would expand to `if y=="Y"` and that would be false, because the first string contains no quotes and the second string contains quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If your target Opertaing Systems are Windows Vista or later, I would suggest you use `choice.exe` for user input consisting of one of a small pre-defined set of known responses.

In the example below, I've included some code to try to pre-determine if the chassis is a laptop/notebook. If that cannot be determined the prompt for input will be invoked.

```
@Echo Off

For /F "EOL=C Delims={}" %%A In ('
    ""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" SystemEnclosure Get ChassisTypes 2>Nul"'
) Do For %%B In (%%A) Do If %%B GEq 9 If %%B LEq 10 Set "ResultIs=T"
If Not "%ResultIs%"=="T" ("%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /M "Is this a laptop"
    If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :Continue)

Rem Laptop specific code goes here
Echo You are using a laptop

:Continue
Rem The rest of your code goes here
Echo Continuing . . .
Pause
```